# Problem using crmsvcutil to generate data context class

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am trying to retrieve data from Microsoft Dynamics CRM database. In order to have LINQ functionality, I applied crmsvcutil to generate data context class. The following is the command line I used

```
crmsvcutil /connectionString:"Authentication Type=SPLA; Server= http://our-crm.com; User ID=user; Password=pass" /namespace:Stub.Xrm /dataContextPrefix:MyCorp /out:Xrm.cs
```

When running the command, I got

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
```

Error. I was able to access http://our-crm.com by using user/pass to assess the CRM. I am suspecting that the URL of serer was the problem, but don't know exactly which one I should use.

The CRM version I used is 4.0

**UPDATE On May 19, 2011:**
I changed the connection string to

```
crmsvcutil /connectionString:"Authentication Type=AD; Server= http://our-crm.com/CRM; User ID=domain\user; Password=pass" /namespace:Stub.Xrm /dataContextPrefix:MyCorp /out:Xrm.cs
```

Now I am getting

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ApplicationException:   0x80040220
  SecLib::CheckPrivilege failed. Returned hr = -2147220960, User: f26255aa-997a-e011-b1ff-0050569e0924, PrivilegeId: a33
11f47-2134-44ee-a258-6774018d4bc3
```

Does it mean I do not have enough privilege to retrieve WSDL information? But I was able to use browser to get http://our-crm.com/mscrmservices/2007/CrmServiceWsdl.aspx and I was able to add webreference to the WebService using same credential.

Comment: Did you enter your credentials in a web form or in a windows credential popup?

Comment: When I access the crm system from browser, I entered credentials in a windows credential popup. Does it mean I should have authentication type as "AD" instead of SPLA?

Comment: I changed Authentication Type to AD and username to domain\user. I got one step further, the output console printed "Building list of suggested names..." but then same exception message printed again.

Comment: Does the user account have privileges for reading metadata (entities, relationships, ...)? crmsvcutil.exe uses the metadata service. It does not use the WSDL.

Comment: @ckeller While your answer didn't do the trick. The comment above pointed me to the right direction. I can now generate my classes, so I will mark your answer as the answer :)

Comment: @WeiMa could you please tell us how you fixed it?  I'm getting the same error after I see "Building list of suggested names..."

Comment: @jayoaK We had moved on from Version 4.0. With CRM2011, we didn't have the same problem.

Comment: @WeiMa yep that was it, we had to use the crmsvcutil.exe that was included in version 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are accessing Dynamics CRM OnPremise with the credentials of the current user, you have to specify `Integrated`as authentication type.

Therefore your connection string should be

```
/connectionString:"Authentication Type=Integrated; Server= http://our-crm.com;
```

If you have to specify a specific user, you have to use `AD`

```
/connectionString:"Authentication Type=AD; Server= http://our-crm.com; User ID=user-domain\user-name; Password=user-password
```

See [Connect to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681567.aspx)